# "=~" and "!~" operator makes odd hash count in Perl when passed in a subroutine

Tags: perl

I am making a subroutine that accepts an array of hashes that have the same keys with different values. As a requirement, there are values that have conditional operations.

sample:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub test {
  my @data = @_;
  print Dumper(@data);
}

test(
  {
    'value' => 1 == 2
  },
  {
    'value2' => 4 == 4
  }
);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'value' => ''
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'value2' => 1
        };
```

but when I use `=~` or `!~` operators, the interpreter outputs this error:

`Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at ...`

```
test(
  {
    'value' => 1 == 2
  },
  {
    'value2' => 'a' =~ /b/
  }
);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'value' => ''
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'value2' => undef
        };
```

It seems that for false statements the hash value returns `undef` not `''`.
I also tried putting undef directly on the hash value and it works ok.

Question:

1. Why does perl outputs this behavior?
2. What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The match operator in list context returns an empty list on failure. You could use

```
scalar( 'a' =~ /b/ )
```

or

```
'a' =~ /b/ ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: oh, sorry, I meant 'a' =~ /b/. I will edit the question

Comment: `scalar 'a' =~ /b/` seems clean and it worked for me. thanks!